# H.264 media player with JavaFX

Tags: javafx, stream, raspberry-pi, media-player, ip-camera

I am trying to display a H.264 stream (of the Raspberry Pi camera, thanks to uv4l) in a JavaFX app. H.264 is supposed to be supported by JavaFX. However, I keep getting a blank screen and this error :

> MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : Unrecognized file signature!
>       at javafx.scene.media.Media._setError(Media.java:513)
>       at javafx.scene.media.Media$InitLocator.run(Media.java:566)
>      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Here's my code :

```
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

 private static MediaView mv = new MediaView();
 private Media media;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
 }
 @Override
 public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
     media = new Media("http://192.168.0.10:8080/stream/video.h264");
     MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(media);
     mp.setAutoPlay(true);
     mv.setMediaPlayer(mp);
     Group root = new Group(mv);
     Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
     stage.setTitle("Pi_Cam");
     stage.setScene(scene);
     stage.show();
     mp.errorProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
         newValue.printStackTrace();
     });
 }
}
```